# Error while encode HEVC using Android MediaCodec on Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, hevc

I try using HEVC encoder support in Android MediaCodec for my stream app.
It's succeed when i using H64 but crashed when i switch to HEVC.

I tested in Samsung Galaxy S6 with Android 7.0, it crash while i queue a buffer to encoder.
No problem when i using MediaRecorder with HEVC.

My init code here:

```
        MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(CUR_CODEC, 640, 480);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 500000);
        format.setInteger("bitrate-mode", 2);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 30);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, -1);

        try {
            mEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(CUR_CODEC);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mEncoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        mEncoder.start();
        outputBuffers = mEncoder.getOutputBuffers();
```

It run success with the log:

```
8-16 10:53:22.120 2285-2285/com.example.hanhnv.camapp I/ACodec:  [] Now uninitialized
08-16 10:53:22.121 2285-5049/com.example.hanhnv.camapp I/ACodec: [] onAllocateComponent
08-16 10:53:22.125 2285-5049/com.example.hanhnv.camapp I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
08-16 10:53:22.134 2285-5049/com.example.hanhnv.camapp I/ACodec: Set Google AAC Dec for aacProfile 0
08-16 10:53:22.190 2285-5049/com.example.hanhnv.camapp I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.HEVC.Encoder] Now Loaded
08-16 10:53:22.196 2285-5049/com.example.hanhnv.camapp I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.HEVC.Encoder] using color format 0x13 in place of 0x7f420888
08-16 10:53:22.202 2285-5049/com.example.hanhnv.camapp I/ACodec: Success set VideoMinQP(0/0/0) VideoMaxQP(50/50/50)
08-16 10:53:22.203 2285-5049/com.example.hanhnv.camapp I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.HEVC.Encoder] cannot encode color aspects. Ignoring.
08-16 10:53:22.203 2285-5049/com.example.hanhnv.camapp I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.HEVC.Encoder] cannot encode HDR static metadata. Ignoring.
08-16 10:53:22.203 2285-5049/com.example.hanhnv.camapp I/ACodec: setupVideoEncoder succeeded
08-16 10:53:22.222 2285-5049/com.example.hanhnv.camapp I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.HEVC.Encoder] Now Loaded->Idle
08-16 10:53:22.256 2285-5049/com.example.hanhnv.camapp I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.HEVC.Encoder] Now Idle->Executing
08-16 10:53:22.258 2285-5049/com.example.hanhnv.camapp I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.HEVC.Encoder] Now Executing
```

This is my encode code:

```
        ByteBuffer data = mNewFrame.duplicate();
        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mEncoder.getInputBuffers();
        int inputBufferIndex = mEncoder.dequeueInputBuffer(0);
        if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
            inputBuffer.clear();
            inputBuffer.put(data);
            mEncoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, mNewDataSize, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0);
            Log.d(TAG, "addFrame " + System.nanoTime() / 1000 + "data size=" + mNewDataSize);

            mTotalFrame++;
            getEncodedFrame();

            mNewFrame = null;
            return true;
        }
```

And it raise an error while i dequeInputBuffer or queueInputBuffer and crashed with log:

```
08-16 10:53:22.293 3195-5087/? E/ExynosVideoEncoder: MFC_Encoder_Set_EncParam: Failed to SetControls
08-16 10:53:22.293 3195-5087/? E/EXYNOS_HEVC_ENC: [0xe4c1b500][HEVCCodecSrcSetup] Failed to set encParam
08-16 10:53:22.293 3195-5087/? E/EXYNOS_HEVC_ENC: [0xe4c1b500][Exynos_HEVCEnc_SrcIn] Failed to HEVCCodecSrcSetup(0xe8009000)
08-16 10:53:22.294 2285-5049/com.example.hanhnv.camapp E/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.HEVC.Encoder] ERROR(0x80001000)
08-16 10:53:22.294 2285-5049/com.example.hanhnv.camapp E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001000, internalError -2147483648)
08-16 10:53:22.294 2285-5048/com.example.hanhnv.camapp E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0x80001000, actionCode 0, while in state 6
```

I think that i used wrong setting for the encode before encoding. It run success if a change the codec to H264.
Any one can help me please.
Thank for your focus.

Comment: I don't think Samsung Galaxy S6 provide h/w acceleration for HEVC encoding, while software encoder is too cpu-intensive to a mobile ap to support, so the HEVC encoder is absent and it's very normal for you to receive this error message.

Comment: Hi @tibetty, i checked and it has h/w acceleration for HEVC encoding by using createEncoderByType API, it's name is OMX.Exynos.HEVC.Encoder. As you see in the log, it loaded succeed

Comment: Yup, I saw it this time and I also found that S6 support HEVC recording from other source (https://www.techspot.com/article/1131-hevc-h256-enconding-playback/page2.html).  Right now I could not give you more advice except removing/adding format configuration one by one.